# Nupkg file not being generated in output DIR

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Im trying to create a nuget package for my .net Winforms Control Library. I have a central repository for all nuget packages so tht i can use it as a local nuget repository. My understanding was that if i check **Generate NuGet package on build** under the *Package* tab of the project properties, and set the **Output Path** under *Build* that the nuget file should be created there.
However its creating in the bin directory. Another weird thing i noticed is my documentation file is actually creating the in output path i specified. Just not the dll's or pgk file.

[image: Output path]
[image: Generate NuGet package]

Can anyone please tell me how to properly specify the location the nuget file should be generated to?

P.s. The project is a .net 5 project targetted to also support net472 & net45
I should also note that i have a plain c# library that does build everything to the output path.

Edit:
[image: Project settings]

Comment: Do you update the visual studio to the latest version?

Comment: Yeh i do, i was running v16.10.0 and updated to 16.10.2 (latest release) but that didn't fix the issue

Comment: Do you set other options about generated path in project? I created a new project and it can work as normal. If possible, you can also try to delete .vs folder or repair your visual studio.